# How can I disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in apache?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, pci-dss

Does anyone know why i can't disable tls 1.0 and tls1.1 by updating the config to this.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

After doing this, i reload apache I do an ssl scan using ssllabs or comodo ssl tool, and it still says tls 1.1 and 1.0 are supported. I would like to remove these?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When you have multiple TLS VirtualHosts and use Server Name Indication (SNI) it is an allowed syntax to have a [`SSLProtocol`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol)  directive for each VirtualHost, but unless you have IP VirtualHosts in practice the settings from the first occurrence of the `SSLProtocol` directive are used for the whole server and/or **all** name-based VirtualHosts supporting TLS<sup>[1](https://serverfault.com/q/637344/37681)</sup>.

So check your main `httpd.conf` (and all included snippets from for instance `conf.d/*.conf` and similar includes)  for more occurrences of the `SSLProtocol` directive.

You syntax is correct, although I agree with [ezra-s' answer](https://serverfault.com/a/848181/37681) that, when you expand the `all` shorthand, you can slightly improve upon:

```
 SSLProtocol +SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

by simply using:

```
 SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

Comment: This all makes sense however I did what you recommended. I grep'd my /etc/httpd directory for all references of "SSLProtocol" . I then updated it to  SSLProtocol TLSv1.2, then did a restart and it still shows that tls 1.0 and 1.1 is supported.  I also tried it on another one of my servers and same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: False alarm, this was indeed cached by comodo and ssllabs reports. It seems to be reporting correctly now. Thank you.

Comment: I think I would recommend using "all" with minus for the protocols you don't want. Future versions of apache define "all" differently as new standards are developed and old standards are found to be insecure.

Comment: if you are using Letsencrypt, do not forget to check `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf`

Comment: As `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` is outside of `/etc/apache`, it is easily overseen by anyone relying on `grep -r`. I just ran into that problem myself and therefore cannot emphasize @Memes' statement enough.

Comment: I would not use `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` variant, as it will miss new TLS protocol when it comes. You will have to remember that somewhere you explicitly set protocol, and have to add new one once TSLv1.4 comes. It's not future-proof.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as Vincas: don't limit yourself to one protocol.  It will bite you down the road.

Answer (score 11):

that you have specified is enough, it shouldn't show any other protocols. Remember SSLLABS caches recent tests. Although knowing that there are no other protocols defining it like you did is kind of convoluted on purpose.

In any case you can use that or simply:

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Is there any difference if you specify `-ALL +TLSv1.2`?

Comment: "All" expands to "+SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2". I don't see a benefit to using "-All". Actually, from the documentation it's not clear that "-all" is even valid syntax. You can do [+/-]protocol but all isn't a protocol: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html

Comment: `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` is indeed shorter than the common approach with negative lists of outdated protocols. However, you will not be able to automatically take advantage of newer protocols like TLSv1.3.

Answer (score 9):

I was struggling with this issue as well, modifying configs with the `SSLProtocol` directive wasn't working. I ended up adding the following to my virtual host configuration:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Protocol "-ALL, TLSv1.2"
```

Which worked perfectly. You can read more about the `SSLOpenSSLConfCmd` directive [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslopensslconfcmd).

Comment: Look for your system version, and check if TLSv1.3 is available. If is, add it to config.

Answer (score 7):

Disable TLS1.0 version in Apache.

If you have multiple virtual hosting then you have to update all configurations file, otherwise,ssl.conf is enough.

To check TSL supporting version:

```
# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 192.168.11.10 | grep TLSv
|   TLSv1.0:
|   TLSv1.1:
|   TLSv1.2:
```

Modify the Apache configuration file `vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/web.conf` remove all TLS and allow only TLS1.2.

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

Validate after the modification.

```
# grep SSLProtocol /etc/httpd/conf.d/web.conf
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2

# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 192.168.11.10 | grep TLSv
|   TLSv1.2:
# service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable both TLS 1.2 and 1.3 this way
and have everything deprecated disabled.

```
  SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!kRSA:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!3DES
```

[image: cdn77.com/tls-test result]

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of fine answers here, but they did not work for me or were actually overkill.  The following suggestions were tested on Ubuntu 16.04 Apache 2.

A key observation is that the first virtual host on that port dictates the setting... **even if its configuration doesn't explicitly specify a SSLProtocol value**.

To determine the first virtual host:

```
bash
source /etc/apache2/envvars
apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
exit
```

On CentOS, only one line will probably be needed:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

When you do this you should see a list of the virtual hosts and it might include a 443 section something like

```
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
     default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
     port 443 namevhost sample.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sample.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
     port 443 namevhost another.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/another.org-le-ssl.conf:2)
     port 443 namevhost lucky.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lucky.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
             alias test15a.zzzzpost.com
```

When you see this, you might find that it's sufficient to update the SSLProtocol config for just that "default server" virtual host.

Another complication that you might run in to with earlier suggestions is that if you grep for occurrences of SSLProtocol in your /etc/apache2/ or /etc/httpd/ tree, you will not find configuration in other parts of your file system.   This can be important if your configuration has Include directives.  For example, if you've used the Let's Encrypt installer, it often adds these:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c> 
<VirtualHost *:443>  
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ...
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf 
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So my suggestions are:

```
1. Determine the first virtual host on the given port.  See my example above 
   for details.
2. Inspect the configuration for that virtual host carefully.    
   a. If you find that config file explicitly sets SSLProtocol, make your change there.
   b. If not, but you find it includes a config file that is setting SSLProtocol, 
      consider setting it there.
   c. Otherwise, it's likely that setting it in your ssl.conf file would work.
   d. If not, consider creating your own config file with your SSLProtocol setting
      and including it in this first virtual host config, and possibly all virtual 
      host configs.
```

As mentioned by others, the configuration you want is

```
SSLProtocol             TLSv1.2
```

After you make your change, you can quickly confirm it via:

```
systemctl reload apache2    
# This ^^^ must be done before vvvv
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 sample.com | grep TLSv
```

If you've been successful, this lists only `TLSv1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too.
I couldn't disable TLSv1 or TLSv1.1 for just one VHost by configuring it within this Vhost.

We found two solution:

1 -

Since we run several IP addresses within one Instance I disabled TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 per IP address, and so for the defined Vhosts too.

2 -

When we only configure strong ciphers, then it seams that only TLSv1.2 is available

```
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Apache 2.4.23, openssl 1.0.2.

Maybe someone can verify my observations.

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

For me, after spending an hour pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my website kept offering TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 - even after manually editing the letsencrypt override that was included automatically.. I realized that I was using Cloudflare, and that Cloudflare is still offering TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 by default in 2023. Crazy. Anyway, if anyone reading this is experiencing this same problem, then you can set a minimum TLS version in Cloudflare as follows (for free): https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/additional-options/minimum-tls/

Answer (score -1):

You need to restart the Apache service using the following command to reflect the changes.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Below code will work fine for me, you can check this article to get more details,
https://karthikekblog.com/how-to-disable-enable-ssl-tls-protocols-in-ubentu-apache-linux-server/

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificates/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificates/certificate.key 
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certificates/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This will not disable anything. It will only enable TLSv1.2. And how to restart varies from distribution to distribution, and even between versions in the same distribution.